# not alerting the variable value passed from onclick php function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

on click,
a)I am not getting alert, when i pass $picname variable to jquery img function(the value of the $picname is tulips.jpg)

b)i am getting the alert (22) when i pass the variable $picid(the value of the $picid is 22)

i think jquery function does not alert images extentions,if so then how can i pass the image name variable whose value having extension,to the jquery function to use its value

```
function profile(){


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM profile");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $picname= $row['picname'];
        $picid= $row['id'];

        ?>


    <table  style="margin-left: 110px">




        <tr><td><a href="#img" class="ok"><img style='width: 200px' src="images/<?php echo $picname ?>"   alt="name" onclick=img(<?php echo $picname ?>);  ></a></td></tr>


    </table>
<?php


}}
```

jquery function is

```
function img(n){
alert(n);
}
```

Comment: first quote your `onclick="img('<?php echo $picname ?>')"` and remove the semicolon

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the single quote for JS strings and it wouldn't also be bad to use a double quote to wrap the value of the `onclick` attribute

```
onclick="img('<?php echo $picname ?>')"
             ^                      ^
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the problem

```
<a href="#img" class="ok"><img style='width: 200px' src="images/<?php echo $picname ?>"   alt="name" onclick=img(<?php echo $picname ?>);  ></a>
```

should be

```
<a href="#img" class="ok"><img style='width: 200px' src="images/<?php echo $picname ?>"   alt="name" onclick="img('<?php echo $picname ?>')"  ></a>
```